# Is there a log analyzer that will parse IIS logs into a database that can be viewed?

Tags: iis, database, logging

I am looking for a tool that will dump its findings into an external database, such as sql.  It doesnt have to be SQL we just want the data in some form of a database so we can manipulate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does it have to be a database? You can use MS' own LogParser to manipulate the hell out of the logs to begin with, and not have to use an intermediate SQL layer.

Actually, LogParser can output to SQL as well, so you could use it to do exactly what you want, as well.

Comment: LogParser does a very nice job of reading and outputing the logs.  Personally I like to push the log data into a RDBMS for detailed analysis.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the info.  It took a little playing around to get it right but I believe this will do exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider a centralized syslog repository like [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) that allows you to search logs from all your servers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ManageEngine [EventLog Analyzer](http://www.manageengine.com/products/eventlog/index.html) can parse the IIS logs into MySQL or MS SQL database. The full feature trial version takes care of your requirement.